# how to get all the TextViews values in the application?

Tags: android, string, textview

i'm trying to find out if it is possible to (programmatically) get all the TextViews values in the application and save them in an ArrayList ??

```
ArrayList <TextView> textViews=new ArrayList<>();    
ViewTreeObserver vto = getWindow().getDecorView().getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        getAllText((ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView());
    }
});
void getAllText(ViewGroup viewGroup){


if (viewGroup == null) return;
for (int i=0; i<viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
{
    View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) getAllText((ViewGroup) view);
    if (view instanceof TextView){
        if(!(textViews.contains(view)))textViews.add((TextView) view);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: is u have object of textview than u can do this work

Comment: yes., you can do it. Please provide more details.

Comment: solution: recursively iterate all children views and check if they are TextView instance ... if so cast to TextView get the value and store in ArryList ... looks like a basic programming excercise(and everyones who wana to be a programmer should be able to do this by them self)

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia

Answer (score 1):

Use something like that:

```
private ArrayList<TextView> mTextViews;

@Override
onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    ViewGroup root = findViewById(R.id.root);

    mTextViews = new ArrayList<>();

    findTextViews(root);
}

private findTextView(ViewGroup root) {
    for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = root.getChildAt(i);

        if (child instanceof TextView) {
             mTextViews.add(child);
        } else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
             findTextView((ViewGroup) child);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is great but there is one problem is that when the textview is in a listView it wouldn't be saved in the arraylist because it needs a thread or a global layout listener which it has a problem it self that  it gets only the text that is shown on the display at the moment , so when scroll down or up in a listview for example the text that was not sown wont be saved in the arraylist